# Help on Regression Analysis (ROC, multinomial)

Tags: regression, spss, roc

I am currently looking at continuous data and seeking a correlation with the presence (and severity, ie, normal, mild, moderate, severe) of a disease entity. Now, so far, running Spearman on SPSS, I've gotten an R of 0.370, p<0.001.

I need help on a couple of things. Can/Should I perform a multinomial regression analysis? Also, I'd like to generate a ROC and find out corresponding cut-off values that may pertain to the severity of the disease, i.e., Normal, Mild, Moderate, Severe.

Please advise on how to go about this. Any input is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site.

What is/are your dependent and independent variables (if any)? Regression analysis is for relating a DV to one or more IVs. Multinomial is appropriate if the DV is categorical with more than 2 categories that are not ordered. That doesn't sound like the case you are dealing with.

Why are you trying to find cut-off values? Categorizing a continuous variable is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Peter! The DV is the disease. It is subcategorized into its severity, ie 0-normal, 1-mild, 2-moderate, 3-severe. I am trying to find cut-off values because my hypothesis is the bigger my IV is (which is a unit of measurement), the more severe my DV category is. I'd like to arrive at something like <3 is normal, 4-5 is mild, 6-7 moderate, >7 severe.

Comment: If your independent variable is continuous, there is no need to categorize it. You can do ordinal logistic regression with an ordinal DV (disease) and a continuous IV.

Comment: I see. Now, can I proceed with ROC analysis? If yes, do I use the real values or do I use the predicted probabilities? I apologize, I'm really confused.

Comment: You should be able to generate something at least similar to an ROC curve from those results. What software are you using?

Comment: I am using SPSS. Whether to use the actual value or saved predicted probabilities from running a regression analysis, I am at a complete loss.

Comment: I don't know anything about `SPSS`. Sorry

Comment: It's ok. I'm actually more concerned on how to come up with the cut-off points corresponding to the disease severity using ROC. You've been very helpful so far, thank you.